# Set LockScreen Wallpaper Programmatically Android

Tags: android, picasso, lockscreen, android-wallpaper

I am building a wallpaper application using `unsplash` api. I have fetched the images and displayed in the app. I have a button which shows a dialog to set as home screen (works fine) or lock screen wallpaper.

The problem here occurs when I try to set the lock screen wallpaper, it doesn't change the image on lock screen. Here's my code snippet for this:

```
setBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (validate()) {
                if (homeCheckBox.isChecked() && largeURL != null) {
                    setHomeWallpaper(largeURL);
                    getDialog().dismiss();
                }

                if (lockCheckBox.isChecked() && largeURL != null) {
                    setLockWallpaper(largeURL);
                    getDialog().dismiss();
                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Select an Option", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

and to set lock screen wallpaper:

```
private void setLockWallpaper(final String largeURL) {
    final WallpaperManager wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getActivity());
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24){
        if (wpm.isSetWallpaperAllowed()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Lock Screen Wallpapers Supported");
            makeLockWallpaper(wpm, largeURL);
            getDialog().dismiss();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Your Device Does Not Support Lock Screen Wallpapers", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        makeLockWallpaper(wpm, largeURL);
        getDialog().dismiss();
    }
}

private void makeLockWallpaper(final WallpaperManager wpm, final String largeURL) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public void run() {
            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(largeURL);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                InputStream stream = Utils.bitmapToStream(bitmap);

                // set wp
                wpm.setStream(stream, null, true, WallpaperManager.FLAG_LOCK);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

To set the homescreen wallpaper, I have used `Picasso` like this and it works:

```
private void setHomeWallpaper(String largeURL) {
    final WallpaperManager wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getActivity());
    Picasso.with(getActivity())
            .load(largeURL)
            .into(new Target() {
                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                    try {
                        wpm.setBitmap(bitmap);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Your New Wallpaper Has Been Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        getDialog().dismiss();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Bitmap Load Failed");
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Could Not Set Wallpaper...Choose Another", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    getDialog().dismiss();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Prep to Load Bitmap");
                }
            });
}
```

but due to the flag for lock screen I have to use either `setStream or setResource`. Does anyone know if Picasso can solve this, as at least I know if the image is ready or not due to `Picasso callbacks` or suggest me an improvement to my code to set lockscreen wallpaper. Thanks.

Comment: Such a beautiful yet lonesome question. I was hoping you had gotten an answer.. Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WallpaperManager` to set wallpaper on lock screen and home screen.

**To Set Wallpaper on Lock Screen:**

```
  WallpaperManager.getInstance(this)
                    .setBitmap(bitmap, null, true, WallpaperManager.FLAG_LOCK)
```

**To Set Wallpaper on HomeScreen:**

```
        WallpaperManager.getInstance(this)
                .setBitmap(bitmap, null, true, WallpaperManager.FLAG_SYSTEM)
```